Remove duplicate characters from a string : Pyspark
I want to keep only the unique alphabets in a pyspark string Column.Please suggest any solution without using udfs. I need a Pyspark solution, not the multiple pythonic solutions present on the forum. Thanks
Input
Col
abcbb12b
Output
Col
abc
I tried using re.sub but couldnot make it work

We can leverage regular expression and pyspark sql functions to achieve the end goal.
Input
+--------+
|   value|
+--------+
|abcbb12b|
+--------+

Import necessary package
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws, collect_list, posexplode, regexp_replace, row_number, split


Remove non-alphabates

df = df.withColumn("alphabet", regexp_replace("value", "[^a-zA-Z$]", ""))


Remove duplicate characters

# a. Explode the values along with their position
df = df.select("value", "alphabet", posexplode(split("alphabet", "")).alias("index", "character"))

# b. Use window function to filter the first characters
df = df.withColumn("character_count", row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("value", "character").orderBy("index")))
df = df.orderBy("index").filter("character_count = 1")

# c. Lets join it together
df = df.groupBy("value").agg(collect_list("character").alias("alphabet_set"))
df = df.select("value", "alphabet_set", concat_ws("", "alphabet_set").alias("alphabet_join"))

# d. Display
df.show()

Output
+--------+--------+------------+
|   value|alphabet|alphabet_set|
+--------+--------+------------+
|abcbb12b|  abcbbb|         abc|
+--------+--------+------------+

